# vala webkit context menu

Tags: webkit, vala

How to remove defaut context menu in vala?
https://valadoc.org/webkit2gtk-4.0/WebKit.ContextMenu.html

this code, not working
var cm = new WebKit.ContextMenu();
cm.remove_all();

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://valadoc.org/webkit2gtk-4.0/WebKit.WebView.context_menu.html), you could do something like that.

```vala
my_web_view.context_menu.connect ((menu, evt, hit_test) => { return true; });
```

This signal is emitted every time a context menu is about to be shown. Returning `true` in the handler will just prevent the menu to appear.

Comment: How?
view.context_menu(cm, Gdk.Event(Gdk.EventType.BUTTON_PRESS));

Comment: No, `context_menu` is a signal not a method, which means that it will be triggered by the object at a certain time (here just before a context menu is shown to the user), on which you can connect a method. That's what I've made in the little example above, by connecting a lambda. With this signal, if the connected method returns true, the context menu is not shown. So just do `view.context_menu.connect ((menu, evt, hit_test) => { return true; });` if your `WebView` is named `view`.

Comment: Hmm ok...
public void xxx(){}
var cm = new WebKit.ContextMenu();
    cm.append(new ContextMenuItem.separator());
    cm.remove_all();
    view.context_menu.connect(cm, xxx);

This code, return error compile.error: Argument 1: Cannot convert from `WebKit.ContextMenu' to `WebKit.WebView.context_menu'

Comment: No, you don't need to create a new `ContextMenu`, just use the code I wrote above. I think you don't understand how lambdas work. By writing `(menu, evt, hit_test) => { return true; }`, I create a new function which takes three arguments (menu, evt and hit_test, and Vala what are their types because they are defined in the signature of the signal) and its body is just `return true;`. If you still don't understand, check out [this page](https://chebizarro.gitbooks.io/the-vala-manual/content/en/lambdas.html), and [this one](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/SignalsAndCallbacks).